# How to change the look of a product on WooCommerce?

Tags: php, css, wordpress, api, woocommerce

Making a affiliate site on WooCommerce and want to change the look of the product. I am using MaterializeCSS as a front end framework so I am trying to fit WooCommerce's functionality into the grid I have created.

Here's a sample of what one product within a "row" looks like in HTML:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col l3 s6">
  <div class="card hoverable">
    <div class="card-image">
      <a href="affiliateurl.com">
        <img src="productphoto.jpg"
          class="padding20">
      </a>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="card-content greybordertop center-align">
      <span class="grey-text text-darken-4 card-title font14 lineheight15">Thermal Sensitive Color Changing Zombie Mug</span>
    </div>

    <a href="affiliateurl.com" class="nospace">
      <div class="card-action center-align">
        VIEW THIS PRODUCT
      </div>
    </a>
    <div>2.99</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As of now, the page just looks like a generic WooCommerce page with generic WooCommerce products: [Generic WooCommerce Products](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH2mh.png).

I would to make it look more like: [Ideal Product Grid and Look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Px6Pq.png).

If anyone has some ideas on how to transform the grid + product look through snippets, overriding CSS or the like it would be greatly appreciated. I feel like I have tried absolutely everything and have gotten nowhere.

EDIT: Should've mentioned first that I am using MaterializeCSS as a framework and have built out the site in HTML/CSS and the hurdle here is to make it WooCommerce compatible.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **existing code** / details any failed [**attempts made so far**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), along with clearly stating what your desired **result** is. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Thanks, edited to include more info in the post :)

Answer (score 0):

I would create a child theme (refer to this article https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/set-up-and-use-a-child-theme/) Then copy only files you want to modify to your child theme folder and code them the way you want. There are more details on how to achieve that in that article.

This approach will prevent you from making changes every time the woocommerce is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm not sure if a child theme would be customizable to that extent. In the WooCommerce Docs it seems like child themes are only used for minor changes.

Comment: You can modify anything you want via a child theme. When wordpress is looking for a file, for example single-product.php, it first looks in a child theme, if the file doesn't exist in a child theme it looks for it in a parent theme. All you need to do is to copy, for exaple single-product.php file from your parent theme into your child theme and make modifications.

Comment: Would you happen to know what kind of PHP snippets I could use to place the price, product title, etc. in the a specific spot? Or where I can find this information? I have looked through the WooCommerce Codex and haven't been able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

What i recommend you is to copy the Theme, change the name in **style.css** and the folder of the copied theme . Do the changes that you want that the old theme wont be harm.